# How to run this .py script correctly?

Tags: python

I downloaded a program called "A ren'py script decompiler," and I cannot for the life of me work out how to run it.

I googled a bit to discover that the files I had downloaded, which were in ".py" format, referred to Python, (yes, this is the level I am on,) so I downloaded it, and after a bit more googling, managed to run the script.

However I have still no idea how to get this thing to actually do what I want, as when I try to copy the commands from the README, it just brings up errors, and half the time I don't even understand what the README is saying in the first place. For example: "You can either use the -b argument to specify the directory in which renpy lies or place the renpy module in your Python module search path." This is gibberish to me.

So I know this is a big ask, but apparently getting this to run is supposed to be pretty simple -- it's just a lightweight program/script/thing that decompiles .rpyc scripts. So does anyone know how I can get it to work?

This is the thing: https://github.com/yuriks/unrpyc

When I run the script in Python it just says:

```
usage: unrpyc.py [-h] [-c] [-b BASEDIR] [-d]
             [--python-screens | --ast-screens | --no-screens | --single-line-screen-kwargs]
             file [file ...]
unrpyc.py: error: too few arguments
```

And then after that I don't know what to type to get it to work anyways.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    --basedir
NameError: name 'basedir' is not defined
```

Comment: Pretty simple, you are missing arguments that you need to provide. You need the help file for the script unless you can see the source in edit mode. That should give you the argument number required for this script.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the maintainer of unpryc

The script should be ran with python 2.7. Also I'm glad to tell you that in the more recent version of the decompiler (http://github.com/CensoredUsername/unrpyc) the dependency on renpy has been removed, so you no longer have to fiddle with the --basedir option.

regarding the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    --basedir
NameError: name 'basedir' is not defined
```

I'd guess that's caused because you're trying to run the command in a python shell instead of a normal command prompt. If you want to call the script normally open a command prompt (I think you're on windows, so it'd be cmd.exe) and run the command:

```
path_to_python_executable unrpyc.py script_you_want_to_decompile.rpyc
```

path_to_python_executable is usually C:\Python27\python.exe

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

You won't need most options; the only one you probably need is the `-b` switch, and of course the script you want to decompile.

The `-b` (or `--basedir`) option tells this script where to find the [Ren'Py source code](http://www.renpy.org/); you need to have that program installed too, and then give the directory where it's Python modules are located to this script. Presumably just downloading the SDK, extracting that somewhere and naming that path with teh `-b` switch is enough:

```
unrpyc.py -b /path/to/renpy/modules/directory script_you_want_to_decompile.rpy
```

Comment: Ok, that looks like it would work - only whatever I start a line with, whether it's "unrpyc.py" or "-b" or "--basedir", I get an error saying "NameError: name 'xxxx' is not defined." Am I doing something wrong, or is this linked to the error that I get when I first run the script, which says about the "too few arguments."?

Thankyou so much for replying though. ^^

Comment: @Kalia: the 'too few arguments' message means the argument parsing from the command line failed. The `NameError` exception means something in the script is broken.

Comment: @Kalia: However, you'll have to update your question to include the full error message if you want us to help you with that. It could be that you simply are using the wrong version of Python (there are two major versions, 2 and 3, and you cannot always run code written for one with the other).

Comment: I think the correct version of Python is Python 2, if I try to run the script in Python 3 it simply tells me "Missing Parentheses in call to print" and won't start at all.

The error message relating to the "arguments" is at the end of my original question, if I added it correctly.

Comment: @Kalia: yes, but we already solved that one; the `NameError` is next.

Comment: Ah, um, is it solved? I mean, it's still there... As for the name error, I think I'm just typing in the line wrong: for example, if I type --basedir it says:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    --basedir
NameError: name 'basedir' is not defined"

But I'm guessing that's because I've entered it wrong?

Comment: That formatting is horrible, I've added it to the original question

Comment: @Kalia: this is a *command line*, not Python code. Run it in your console, not in Python itself.

Comment: Ohhh right okay. Right, I think this will be my last try, I don't want to waste any more of your time. >_< 

I don't understand how to make the console know I want to do stuff with the unrpyc.py file - from your very first suggested line right at the start, I thought it implied you could just type "unrpyc.py" and then all the other stuff -- but then it just gets the "name not defined" error.

Comment: @Kalia: `python unrpyc.py` might work. See  https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts for documentation on how to get Windows to run your Python scripts.